# check for part of a string, read in all then split up

Tags: javascript, jquery

so in different parts of text i will have random links that I need to read in an interpret.

for example the text might be

```
<div id="test">
<li> blah blah</li> 
<li> <!--{Byond:cta|localAction:products:4|Cool Dude}--> blah blah blahs</li> 
<li> blah facility blah**</li> 
<li> No blah of blahpayment</li> </ul> 
<p> <!--{Byond:cta|localAction:contact|Contact Us}--></p> <p> &nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

so first of of all I know i can read it in

```
var text = $("#test").html();
```

and then i could check for

```
if (text.indexOf("Byond:cta|localAction") >= 0) { 
    //do something
{
```

where i have //do something is where now I need to read in each instance of byond:cta|localAction - but i need to read it in from the start point which is `<!--` until the end point which is `-->` and i am not sure how to do this

I am guessing once i have that as a string i can use sting.split to take the data out i need..

Answer (score 0):

You may use RegExp for get neede par of string. Example

```
var expr = /.*<--(Byond:cta|localAction.*)-->.*/i;
var result = expr.exec(text);
console.log(result);
//result[1] must be needed text part
```